# What is the Systems Biology Markup Language?

Tags: sbml

Can someone summarize what SBML is? What does the acronym stand for and what is its purpose? I hear it has something to do with systems biology and computaitonal biology? What kind of computational biology is it used for?

Answer (score 4):

SBML is short for the Systems Biology Markup Language. It is a XML based exchange format for computational models in Systems Biology and Computational Biology. At its heart is the description of process based models via reactions and species. SBML is the de facto standard for exchange of such computational models and it is heavily used to encode kinetic pathway models (e.g. metabolic pathways or signalling networks) or constraint-based metabolic models (e.g. flux balance analysis). SBML consists of a core language and packages which extend its cabilities with additional features. E.g. there is a package for hierarchical model composition or for flux balance analysis. 
For more information see:

- http://sbml.org/
- the latest language specification: [Level 3 Version 2 (L3V2)](http://sbml.org/Special/specifications/sbml-level-3/version-2/core/release-2/sbml-level-3-version-2-release-2-core.pdf)
- The original paper describing SBML: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12611808